# JW Player RTMP Works Embedded, Self Hosted Not

Tags: jwplayer

Stream working with embed, but not self hosted

https://s3.amazonaws.com/jwtestrtmp/embedded.html
https://s3.amazonaws.com/jwtestrtmp/selfhosted.html

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
    playerInstance.setup({
        file: "rtmp://centosstream-k3ds7l33.cloudapp.net/live2/video",
        height: 360,
        autostart: true,
        rtmp: {
            subscribe: true
        },
        width: 640
    });
</script>
```

Same source in both: rtmp://centosstream-k3ds7l33.cloudapp.net/live2/video

Stream is fine, checked in VLC and ffmpeg

Any ideas?

Comment: Got answer form jw, **subscribe: true** is supposedly only for some providers like Akamai, normal rtmp works just fine without that, although one might wanna add **bufferlength** into rtmp block to decrease delay.

Comment: Nice, glad you got that working.